# Fullsimplify works on one, not the other

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Exp[x] is less than 1 if x<0. Both of the following should simplify, only the first does.

```
Clear[a, b, c]
$Assumptions = {a > 0, b > 0, c > 0};
TrigToExp[FullSimplify[Abs[-1 + E^-( a + b)]]]
TrigToExp[FullSimplify[Abs[-1 + E^(-(a + b) c)]]]
```

Yields

```
1 - E^(-a - b)
```

and

```
Abs[-1 + E^(-(a + b) c)]
```

Is there a workaround?

MMA 11.2.0.0 on Macbook Pro Yosemite

Comment: Try `Simplify@ComplexExpand@Abs[-1 + E^(-(a + b) c)]`

Comment: That works! I expected the $Assumptions to inform FullSimplify that the a,b,c were real. Thanks!

Comment: The reason is the default option "ComplexityFunction->LeafCount" of FullSimplify. If you change the ComplexityFunction,ou can taylor the output to your needs. E.g. "ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#[[;; -2]]] &)"

Comment: @DanielHuber The default complexity function depends on `LeafCount` as well, but it is not just that. See [this point in the “Properties&Relations” section of the docs for `ComplexityFunction`](https://wolfram.com/xid/0bnhtcjqmulci-hk3jzl).